# VS2015 supports magic statics, so why this warning?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I'm upgrading from VS2013 to VS2015 and am getting the following warning. I thought VS2015 implemented magic statics so that the local static object should be thread-safe, so what is going on?

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\system_error(698): error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\system_error(704): note: see reference to function template instantiation '_Ty &std::_Immortalize<std::_Generic_error_category>(void)' being compiled
          with
          [
              _Ty=std::_Generic_error_category
          ]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\system_error(698): warning C4640: '_Static': construction of local static object is not thread-safe
```

The error is in the system_error header from the VS installation folder. The error is in this function:

```
template<class _Ty> inline
    _Ty& _Immortalize()
    {   // return a reference to an object that will live forever
    static _Immortalizer<_Ty> _Static;
    return (*reinterpret_cast<_Ty *>(&_Static._Storage));
    }
```

That's all the context there is in the error, and I can't see where system_error actually gets included.

Compiler flags are:

```
/Yu"stdafx.h" /GS /analyze /W3 /wd"4481" /wd"4251" /Zc:wchar_t 
/Zi /Gm- /O2 /sdl /Fd"x64\Release\\Release_vc140.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise
/errorReport:prompt /WX /Zc:forScope /Gd /MT /Fa"x64\Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"x64\Release\" /Fp"x64\Release\MyProj.pch"
```

**Update**

Sorry, it seems fixed now. It looks like I was on the v140_xp toolset and wrong TargetPlatformVersion. This one must have slipped through the net when I thought I'd replaced them all. I'm not quite sure why getting those wrong would result in this error though. Anyway, thanks for the help so far.

Comment: Which compiler flags do you use?

Comment: it is required by standard, and there is nothing magic about it. If MSVC in 2015 fails to follow C++ 11 in such a basic feature, I don't know what to say.

Comment: @SergeyA - what is required by the standard?

Comment: That local static objects are initialized only once and in thread-safe manner.

Comment: There is something magic about it, its name! The feature name is "magic statics"

Answer (score 2):

It looks like its caused by the bogus warning which is turned into an Error, read this connect bug:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2539759/c4640-warning-cannot-be-disabled

The error C2220 indicates you have enables /WX switch, which tells the compiler to treat all warnings as errors.

you can turn this warning off with:

```
#pragma warning (disable : 4640)
```

<del>btw. unrelated, but might be usefull to You. You use `_Immortalizer` as a name for your class which starts with underscore followed by uppercase latter. This is prohibited by standard: read here: [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).</del>

Comment: That's not my class, that's from the standard headers which is where the error occurs.

Comment: @ScottLangham Oh, I understand - If your problem is no longer reproducible then delete question

Comment: I can reproduce it, so I would think this question might still be useful if somebody else has their project incorrectly configured and gets the same error.

Answer (score 2):

It's caused by changes in MSBuild's toolset v140_xp. Issue appears when:

- project builds with VS2015 Update 2, toolset v140_xp
- project configuration is Dynamic Library
- project was created with ATL App Wizard, so *.vcxproj contains tag `<Keyword>AtlProj</Keyword>`

There is workaround: open *.vcxproj file, find tag `<Keyword>AtlProj</Keyword>` and replace it with `<Keyword>Win32Proj</Keyword>`. Nothing will be changed while compiling, but warning will disappear.

If you want to know details, navigate to the directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Platforms\Win32\PlatformToolsets\v140_xp`, open `Toolset.props` and find comment `<!-- Added /Zc:threadSafeInit- for ATL dll projects and enable the C4640 warnning -->`. The line below it enables warning and disables "magic static" feature from C++11.

**P.S.** Please note that warning isn't useless: 'magic static' uses thread-local storage which suffers from ugly WindowsXP kernel bug: access to TLS from DLL causes crash when application built without TLS support. Any DLL plugins with WinXP support affected by this bug.